# Unable to delete all files from directory

Tags: linux, bash, kubernetes, exec, rm

I want to delete all the files under the volume directory. The directory is inside the Kubernetes pod. So I am using the exec command.

My command -

```
kubectl exec $POD -- rm -rf /usr/local/my-app/volume/*
```

The above command is not working. No output of the above command on terminal. I tried with below command and it is working -

```
kubectl exec $POD -- rm -rf /usr/local/my-app/volume
```

But it will delete the directory. I can't delete the directory because it is using for mounting purpose.

How can I achieve the above functionalities?

Thanks

Comment: Will you please update your question with the error that's printed when the command is executed.

Comment: There is no output of command

Comment: check the permission for folders inside /usr/local/my-app/volume/ volume

Comment: @lucy Remove the `-f` option to get output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the wildcard expansion is happening on **your machine** and not the Pod; what you want is to have the shell glob expand on the Pod, which one can accomplish via

```shell
kubectl exec $POD -- sh -c 'rm -rf /usr/local/my-app/volume/*'
```

Comment: awesome. Thanks @mdaniel